# Make div open with your mouse and not click

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, mouse, mouseover

I have make this: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/25y4K/1/) In the right you see a red button. When you click on the red button. The content screen with the text is coming. But i have a question of this. Can i make this with a other animation. If you hold your mouse. Then you can slide open. With your mouse button to left. Then the content box open. Do you understand it? I hope you can help me.

You can see the code on jsfiddle. And you can change it there. I hope you can help me. I am a starting javascripter. And how And have no idea how I can make this.

Comment: You mean you can drag that red label to the left and the content box will move along so that it opens?

Comment: Yeah that i mean. How can i make that

Comment: Are you meaning drag the red button with the left button pressed, to slide the panel, or simple expand the panel when the mouse is hover?

Comment: Yeah that is what i mean Daniel... how can i make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement dragging, you can make use of `mousedown`/`mouseup`/`mousemove` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/25y4K/8/.

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var box = $(".what-is-delicious"),
        button = $(".what-is-delicious > a");

    var mouseDown = false,
        grabbed   = 0,
        start     = -303;

    button.mousedown(function(e) {
        mouseDown = true;
        $('*').bind('selectstart', false); // prevent selections when dragging
        grabbed = e.pageX; // save where you grabbed
        $("body").append('<div class="background-overlay"></div>');
    });

    $('body').mouseup(function() {
        mouseDown = false;
        $('*').unbind('selectstart', false); // allow selections again
        $(".background-overlay").remove();
        start = parseInt(box.css('right'), 10); // save start for next time
                                                // (parseInt to remove 'px')

    }).mousemove(function (e) {
        if(mouseDown) { // only if you are dragging
            // set right to grabbed - pageX (difference) + start 'right' when started
            // dragging. And if you drag too far, set it to 0.
            box.css("right", Math.min(grabbed - e.pageX + start, 0));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah that i am looking. Cool stuff!

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/25y4K/7/)  Basically I just did a couple of things:

- Changed the handler from "click" to "mouseenter"
- Added a "mouseleave" handler that does the opposite thing
- Put the handlers on the "what-is-delicious" container instead of the `<a>`

The code:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict"
    var box = $(".what-is-delicious"),
        button = $(".what-is-delicious > a");
    box.mouseenter(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(button).hasClass("open")) {

        } else {
            $("body").append('<div class="background-overlay"></div>');
            button.addClass("open");
            box.animate({ right: "0"}, 750);
        }
    }).mouseleave(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(button).hasClass("open")) {
            $("body").find('div.background-overlay').remove();
            button.removeClass("open");
            box.animate({ right: -303}, 750);

        } else {
        }
    });
});
```

The "preventDefault()" calls aren't really necessary anymore but I left them there.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are toggling the Style.Display of the DIV currently in an OnClick() event.
The same code can be called from a Hover() or MouseOver()

Comment: How can i make that. Sorry.. Can you give a example on my code in jsfidle